# Android: Rendering with SurfaceTexture to FrameBuffer

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, glsurfaceview, surface

I am working on an effect that requires dual-pass rendering (i.e. two separate shaders are applied in succession). I am using a GLSurfaceView with a custom renderer.

In order to achieve this effect, I am trying to render to a FrameBuffer first, and then to a GL_TEXTURE_2D for display in the GLSurfaceView.

The relevant code in the OnSurfaceCreated method is the following:

```
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, this.textureID, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,this.textureID[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures2D, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures2D[0]);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fboId, 0);
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId[0]);
        GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures2D[0], 0);
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

The relevant code in OnDrawFrame is this:

```
       synchronized (this) {
            if (this.updateSurface) {
                this.surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
                this.surfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(this.stMatrix);
                this.updateSurface = false;
            }
        }

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId[0]);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, this.textureID[0]);

// apply the first shader

        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures2D[0]);

// apply the second shader

        GLES20.glFinish();
```

However, the program is crashing due to glError 1286, which seems to indicate an invalid framebuffer operation. I am not sure what is causing this issue, though I suspect it might have to do with the fact that the SurfaceTexture is associated with a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture, while the FrameBuffer is outputting a GL_TEXTURE_2D texture.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Crashing *where*? Put error-check calls after every GLES operation and see exactly which call is failing.

Comment: It crashes when GLES20.glDrawArrays() is called when the first shader is applied.

Comment: "The command is trying to render to or read from the framebuffer while the currently bound framebuffer is not framebuffer complete (i.e. the return value from glCheckFramebufferStatus is not GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE). The offending command is ignored and has no other side effect than to set the error flag." Are you calling `glCheckFramebufferStatus()`?

Comment: glCheckFramebufferStatus() returns 0, which would seem to indicate that the FrameBuffer is not bound? I'm a little confused why since I seem to be following the methods presented in similar questions (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137625/how-to-execute-2-passes-for-a-blur-effect-in-opengl-es-2-0)

Comment: There's a series of things that must be done for an FBO to be "complete"; walk through the list and check them. https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java#L643 has an example that works on Android.

Comment: I've taken a look at examples like this and some others. The main difference between what I am doing is that the original image in my case comes from a SurfaceTexture bound to a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES rather than a GL_TEXTURE_2D. I'm not sure whether this would cause issues when rendering to a FrameBuffer, or whether it would still be possible to render the final result (GL_TEXTURE_2D) to a GLSurfaceView.

Comment: You can't use an external texture as the FBO target, but there's no reason to do so. The external texture shouldn't be relevant to your FBO setup, since it's just something you sample from during your first rendering pass.

Comment: I intend to use a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` as the final target of the FBO, so I set it up that way in `GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D()`. What I am not sure of is how to make the FBO sample from the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` for the first rendering pass. Is calling `GLES20.glBindTexture()` on the texture to be sampled from sufficient, and then I just set up the FBO as though it was sampling from a `GL_TEXTURE_2D`?

Comment: Focus on getting the output pipeline to work. Draw a pattern with a few `glClear()` calls and run it all the way through the multi-pass system. Once that works, add the external texture source.

Comment: On a side note, is it even possible to render to a FrameBuffer attached to a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` if the source is a `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`? Would the differences in texture formats cause a conflict?

Comment: There is no relationship that I am aware of between the configuration of the framebuffer and the set of operations you are allowed to use to draw on it.